# SQL Using a String Function on Indexed Column Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, sql-server-2005

I have a general question regarding using String Functions and their impact on performance. 
I have a table with a non-clustered index on column ID. The column has 20 digit varchar in it. 
When I run :

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM tbl
WHERE ID = '00000000009123548754'
```

The result comes back very fast.
But when I run

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM tbl
WHERE RIGHT(ID, 10) = '9123548754'
```

It takes a very long time.
The estimated execution plan for the first query has a Index Seek, where as for the second query is has a Index Scan.

I understand that the Seek as oppose to the Scan is the reason one is faster, but why does the String Function Right() has such an impact?

Comment: If there are 20 digits, then the second will return no rows.

Comment: Well, RIGHT() cannot work in conjunction with the hashed values your index is based upon, so it has to evaluate every ID value. Try and run Database Engine Tuning Advisor against your query and see what it comes up with.

Comment: What version of what database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005

Comment: How many rows are we talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason there is a difference is because the `RIGHT(ID,10)` has to be resolved for every row in order to filter it (hence the scan), whereas the `ID = '00000000009123548754'` clause can be resolved to a simple seek.

In technical terms, your first query is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), while the second isn't (due to the function).